# How to get webserver on Kali to open on other network computers? will only open on host

Tags: apache-http-server, webserver

So in Kali I type in sudo service apache2 restart.  When I open my browser on that PC and put in my IP address it returns the page index.something html but does not show any other files in the folder.  When I plug my IP into a browser on a different PC it cannot connect and shows nothing.  So how do I make it so it will open on other browsers on the network and show all the files in the directory?

So I am kinda a noob so instructions are necessary.  Anyhow I tried using simple http server which I was able to get the files to show up when I started it in the dir I wanted.  However, I am still having the issue of opening it on another PC either from apache2 server or simplehttp.  If anyone can give directions to serve files so that someone on my network can type in my ip and it will go to my webserver I would appreciate.  So far comments were unhelpful unfortunately.

So I typed hotname -i into term and is reported 127.0.1.1 and I put that address into the browser and apache is working to show the files in the dir.  However, still am not able to open it on another pc browser.

Comment: From Kali, you can SMB://IPorNameofOtherComputer/folder   .   Does that help you?  Posted from my Kali machine..   If trying to get into Kali (or other Linux) from Windows you may need to install and configure Samba

Comment: run `netstat -ntlup` and note what the local address is for apache (the process on port 80). if its 127.x.y.1 then apache is configured to only serve pages to the local host. if that is the case, look in your apache config for a "listen" statement, and set it to `Listen 0.0.0.0:80`